# Android VectorDrawable not scaling up

Tags: android, android-vectordrawable

I have a simple circle view drawable which is to be stretched and filled in an ImageView. But I keep getting a large white space between the circle and the ImageView bounds. I am supporting API 21+ and this code is being tested on Android 8.1.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="100dp"
    android:height="100dp"
    android:viewportHeight="64"
    android:viewportWidth="64"
    >
    <path
        android:fillColor="#ff00ff"
        android:pathData="M22,32
        A10,10 0 1,1 42,32
        A10,10 0 1,1 22,32 Z" />
</vector>
```

ImageView XML:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/simple_circle_vector"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

AppCompatImageView doesn't work either:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/simple_circle_vector" />
```

I have tried multiple width/height options, but the drawable never scales up.

Answer (score 0):

There is a trick to solve your problem fast, use your drawable as background for your imageView.

Comment: Tried that already (both on a simple View and ImageView), doesn't work